# What format should be the boxplot [echarts] data to avoid the transform function, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, echarts

Set of parameters [min, Q1, median, Q3, max] for boxplot I have initially, how can I render them in echarts

echarts for boxplot transforms the original data to the set [min, Q1, median, Q3, max], can I avoid this step ? My source data already consists of [min, Q1, median, Q3, max] sets, how do I pass such a set to render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just your parameters for the `data` attribute.

```js
series: {
 name: 'boxplot',
 type: 'boxplot',
 data:[[min, Q1, median, Q3, max]]
}
```

Link for Echarts documentation https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-boxplot.data

Comment: Thanks a lot. Further i'll be more attentive.